# Python conditional statement problem (logic) please go through body for problem description

Tags: python

```
def gender_checker(sex="unknown"):
    if sex=="m":
        print ("male"):
    elif sex=="f":
        print ("female")
    elif sex is not "m" or "f":
        print (" invalid")
```

""" It's python program..(3.x.xx )
Problem is when no arguments is being passed it should print "unknown" buts its not printed that instead "invalid" is getting printed. What I want is if no args are passed then print default if args passed is in valid then print invalid that its """

Comment: How could this code possibly print "unknown"? There's no `print('unknown')` or `print(sex)` anywhere.

Comment: Even if I put print statment for sex. It wont gonna print out that. It still prints invalid

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The last condition should be:

```
elif sex != "m" or sex != "f":
```

But even simpler:

```
else:
```

Because this will cover all other cases where sex is neither "m" nor "f".

In addition remove the `:` behind `print("male"):`
and let it print after the last (`else:`) clause: `print("unknown")`

Comment: `sex is not "m" or not "f":` doesn't do what you think. Try it with `sex = 'f'`. You expect the result to be `False` but you'll get `True`.

Comment: @ Matthias true! Thanks!

Comment: @ it has to be `sex != 'f'` or `==`.

Comment: `sex != "m" or sex != "f"` is just `True`. It can't be "m" and "f" simultaneously, can it?

Comment: @Aran-Fey: the `or` makes that only one of them has to be true.

Comment: would you elaborate it little better?

Comment: ah it should be rather `if not(sex == "m" or sex == "f"):` or `if sex not in ["m", "f"]:` or easier: `else:` - and @Aran-Fey - I guess I misunderstood you. You are right - if `sex` is `"m"` then the other expression will be `True` and vice versa. So it was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Python **isn't** fully like English writing, so you would have to do:

```
def gender_checker(sex="unknown"):
    if sex=="m":
        print ("male"):
    elif sex=="f":
        print ("female")
    else:
        print ("unknown")
```

Comment: Hey thanks What I want is when user passes no arguments then it should print "unknow" if user enter wrong arguments kike "a" which is invalid so it should print invalid , now suggest me how to modify my code to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding your `if-else statement`. It will print `invalid` since your last `elif` statement is checking if it is not `m` or `f`; I would imagine you want something like this:

```
def gender_checker(sex="unknown"):
    if sex=="m":
        print("male"):
    elif sex=="f":
        print("female")
    elif sex == "unknown":
        print("unknown")
    else:
        print("invalid")
```

Comment: Hey thanks What I want is when user passes no arguments then it should print "unknow" if user enter wrong arguments kike "a" which is invalid so it should print invalid , now suggest me how to modify my code to do this?

Comment: @user9562444 then you would want to add an `elif` statement for `unknown`. I've updated my answer just as how you described it

Comment: Hey thanks this is what i wanted :), Can you point out where i was slipped? i might have misunderstood some concept please clarify this thanks again

Comment: @user9562444 just on your last `elif` statement, as you've mentioned you only needed to check if the user had not provided a gender and by default sex will be set to "unknown" if you don't provide any arguments to `gender_checker`. As you can see in the answer I've added an additional `elif` for sex == "unknown" which covers your default `sex`. The `else` is to cover all other `sex` inputs that are not covered by `m`, `f`, `unknown`. You can mark my post as correct if it answers your question. Thanks!

Comment: thanks for clarification :)